# How can I dynamically change minTime in flatpickr?

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I'm working on a website for a bicycle store that rents bikes online. I'm using flatpickr so users can choose when to pick up their bikes. So far so good.
This bicycle store has different openings times on different days. for example, on Monday they open at 14:00, and on other days they open at 10:00.
How do I change minTime in config so that it adapts to the times above?
This is how far I get:

```
    let minimT = "10:00";

    config = {
    minDate:"today",
    minTime: minimT,
    maxTime:"17:45",
    enableTime: true,
    onChange: function(dateStr){
        //console.info(dateStr);
        const d = new Date(dateStr);
        let day = d.getDay();
        if(day === 1){
          console.log("Monday");
          minimT = "14:00";
        }     
      }
    }

    const fp = flatpickr(".form-input", config);
```

When I run this code, minTime still shows "10:00" instead of "14:00".
What is the best way to go about this?